# Mysql order by rating - but capture all

Tags: mysql, inner-join, rating

I have this PHP/MYSQL code which returns records from a table ordered by their ratings, from highest rated to lowest rated:

```
<table width="95%">
    <tr>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
            $current_page = $_GET['p'];
        } else {
            $current_page = 1;
        }
        $cur_category = $_GET['category'];
        $jokes_per_page = 40;
        $offset = ($current_page - 1) * $jokes_per_page;

        $result = mysql_query("
        select jokedata.id as joke_id, jokedata.datesubmitted as datesubmitted,
        jokedata.joketitle as joke_title, sum(ratings.rating)/count(ratings.rating) as average
        from jokedata inner join ratings
        on ratings.content_type = 'joke' and ratings.relative_id = jokedata.id
        WHERE jokecategory = '$cur_category'
        group by jokedata.id
        order by average desc
        limit $offset, $jokes_per_page
        ");

        $cell = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($cell == 5) {
                echo "</tr><tr class=\"rowpadding\"><td></td></tr><tr>";
                $cell = 1;
            }
            $joke_id = $row['joke_id'];
            $joke_title = $row['joke_title'];
            $joke_average = round($row['average'], 2);

            echo "<td><strong><a class=\"joke_a\" href=\"viewjoke.php?id=$joke_id\">$joke_title</a></strong> -average rating $joke_average.</td>";
            $cell++;
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowpadding"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

It works perfectly but there is one problem - if an item does not have at least one rating, it will not be selected by the query at all!

How can I remedy this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

- use `left outer join` to get jokes that have no ratings
- use `avg()` instead of manually computing average
- possibly use `coalesce()` to avoid `null` values in the result

Here's a simplified version of your tables:

```
create table joke(jokeid int primary key, jokedata varchar(50));
create table ratings(rating int, relative_id int);
insert into joke values(1, "killing");
insert into joke values(2, "no rating");
insert into ratings values(5, 1);
insert into ratings values(10, 1);
```

And some example queries:

```
select joke.jokeid, avg(ratings.rating) as average 
   from joke 
   left outer join ratings 
     on ratings.relative_id = joke.jokeid 
   group by joke.jokeid;
+--------+---------+
| jokeid | average |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |  7.5000 | 
|      2 |    NULL | 
+--------+---------+
```

Or, using `coalesce()`:

```
select joke.jokeid, avg(coalesce(ratings.rating, 0)) as average 
  from joke 
  left outer join ratings 
    on ratings.relative_id = joke.jokeid 
  group by joke.jokeid;
+--------+---------+
| jokeid | average |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |  7.5000 | 
|      2 |  0.0000 | 
+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a left join rather than an inner join, and then handle the case where ratings.ratings is null:

```
$result = mysql_query("
            SELECT jokedata.id AS joke_id, 
            jokedata.datesubmitted AS datesubmitted,
            jokedata.joketitle AS joke_title, 
            -- average is 0 if count or sum is null
            IFNULL(SUM(ratings.rating)/COUNT(ratings.rating), 0) AS average
            FROM jokedata 
            -- return all rows from left table (jokedata), and all nulls for ratings
            -- data when there is no matching row in the right table (ratings)
            LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.content_type = 'joke' AND jokedata.id = ratings.relative_id 
            WHERE jokecategory = '$cur_category'
            GROUP BY jokedata.id
            ORDER BY average desc
            LIMIT $offset, $jokes_per_page
            ");
```

The left join will return all results from jokedata and will just return all nulls for ratings for each row where the join condition is not met.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not selecting them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  jokedata.id as joke_id,
        jokedata.datesubmitted as datesubmitted,
        jokedata.joketitle as joke_title,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  AVG(rating)
        FROM    ratings
        WHERE   ratings.relative_id = jokedata.id
                AND ratings.content_type = 'joke'
        ), 0) AS average
FROM    jokedata
ORDER BY
        average DESC
LIMIE   $offset, $jokes_per_page
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that using the average is a little unfair.  If Joke A has 1 rating of 5 and Joke B has 25 ratings of 4, then Joke A will rank above Joke B.  It gives unpopular jokes more of an advantage to be ranked higher.

I would suggest associating weight to ratings and then ranking by the weight.  For example, on a scale from 1 to 5, 1 would get a -2, 2 would get a -.5, 3 is 0, 4 is +.5 and 5 would get a +2.  So this would allow a joke with 5 "4" ratings to be ranked higher than the joke with 1 "5" rating.

The -2 to +2 scale may need some tweaking, but hopefully you see my point.